# UTF-8 characters with Adafruit_GFX

Tags: utf-8, arduino, adafruit

I am using Arduino with [OPEN-SMART Touch Screen Expansion Shield](http://www.dx.com/p/open-smart-touch-screen-expansion-shield-w-touch-pen-for-arduino-450238#.WU_Mhq31_IF), which uses Adafruit_GFX library. I would need to print characters from whole UTF-8 as for example letters with diactritics, Greek letters and so on. If I try to print these characters with default font, it prints some nonsense. What should I do?

Comment: "*"characters from whole UTF-8*". Are you aware that an Uno has only 32 KB of flash memory?

Comment: I am using Mega with 256 KB of memory and I also thought it could be on SD card, if it was too big. Or do you think, that better solution would be to have some font with non-standard set of characters, which I specifically need, to spare as much memory as possible?

Comment: I don't this 256K of memory will hold **all** the known characters in the world and then some...

Comment: You'd need to pass the fonts' bitmaps to the touch-expansion shield, or generate the text as a bitmap yourself.  You should pick an alphabet at a time, Asian scripts require quite a bit of memory, so you may not need all of them.

Comment: OK, I think, I will just create my own encoding and font and I will add character when I will need it. I was only curious, if something as UTF-8 font for Arduino with TFT exists, but it was probably a bad idea. I really don't need Chinese script.